# Vue bind table key on html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm really new at vuejs and I want to know if its posibble that you can bind a table key on html name tag like this:

```
<tr v-for="(value, k) in table" :key="k">

        <td>
           <input type="text"  name="n_muestra[{{k}}]" >
        </td>
</tr>
```

Or maybe an alternative ?...thanks for your help and excuse my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
:name="`n_muestra[${k}]`"
```

(or `:name="'n_muestra[' + k + ']'"` if you find template string confusing).

Note the colon before `name` (the attribute value will be evaluated as javascript code)